# NDSolve parametric plot

Tags: differential-equations

Here is my code.

```
s = NDSolve[{f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] == 0, f[0] == A, f'[0] == 0, f'[10] == 1}, f, x]
```

I want to plot `f''[0]` with respect to `A` in `[0,3]` range. How can I plot this graph?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is sampling a few data points for different `a` values:

```
pts = Table[
       Module[{A = j},
           s = NDSolve[{y'''[x] + y[x] y''[x] == 0, y[0] == A, y'[0] == 0, y'[10] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}];
       Flatten@{j, y'''[0] /. s}
      ],
{j, 0., 3., 0.1}];
```

Then plot them as:

```
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ParametricNDSolveValue` for this task in two different ways. First, and more convenient way, is to

> use `f''[val]` as the second argument of `ParametricNDSolveValue` to 
>   get a function of the parameter `a` that gives the value of the function `f''` at `t==val`

```
{pf0, pf1, pf5} = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] == 0, f[0] == a, 
      f'[0] == 0, f'[10] == 1}, #, {x, 0, 10}, {a}] & /@ {f''[0], f''[1], f''[5]};

Plot[{pf0[a], pf1[a], pf5[a]}, {a, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01],
  ImageSize -> 400, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"f''[0]", "f''[1]", "f''[5]"},
    LabelStyle -> Directive["Palette", 16], BaseStyle -> Thick, 
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], Above]]
```

[image]

Similarly, using `f[1]`, and `f'[1]` and `f''[1]` as the second argument

```
{pf, fprm1, fprm2} = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] == 0, f[0] == a, 
      f'[0] == 0, f'[10] == 1}, #, {x, 0, 10}, {a}] & /@ {f[1], f'[1], f''[1]};

Plot[{pf[a], fprm1[a], fprm2[a]}, {a, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01], ImageSize -> 400,
 PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"f[1]", "f'[1]", "f''[1]"},
    LabelStyle -> Directive["Palette", 16], BaseStyle -> Thick,
    LegendLayout -> "Row"], Above]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can get a parametric solution for `f` and take its derivative(s):

```
pf = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] == 0, f[0] == a, 
    f'[0] == 0, f'[10] == 1}, f, {x, 0, 10}, {a}];

Row[Plot[Evaluate[{pf[a][x], D[pf[a][x], {x, 1}], D[pf[a][x], {x, 2}]} /. x -> #], 
    {a, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01], ImageSize -> 350,
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"f[" <> ToString@# <> "]", 
        "f'[" <> ToString@# <> "]", "f''[" <> ToString@# <> "]"},
       LabelStyle -> Directive["Palette", 20], BaseStyle -> Thick,
       LegendLayout -> "Row"], Above]] & /@ {0, 1, 5}]
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need to set a value for $a$:

```
s = NDSolve[
  {y'''[x] + y[x] y''[x] == 0,
   y[0] == 1,
   y'[0] == 0,
   y'[10] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 10}]
```

`{{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 10.}}, <>]}}`

```
Plot[Evaluate[y[x] /. s], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[y'''[x] /. s], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]